# Python Scrapy: Global Variable not changes its value under function

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I can't get the Global Variable value changed.

Variable **i** : Don't know if increased and provide its value to **PGroup** in *IF* statement.

```
        global i
        i = i + 1
```

Variable **PGroup**: Doesn't show changes as per *IF* statement.

```
        global PGroup
        if i == 1:
            PGroup == 'Person_1'            
        elif i == 2:
            PGroup == 'Person_2'
        elif i == 3:
            PGroup == 'Person_3'
```

The PGroup values I received after running code is 'TEST' which is what I have declared at the beginning of my code.
Can anyone help? The whole code sequence is below:

```
import scrapy
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
PGroup = 'TEST'
i = 0

class NewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'LEARNING1'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example']
    start_urls = [
                    'https://www.example/abc/',
                    'https://www.example/def/',
                    'https://www.example/ghi/',                
                ]

    def parse(self, response):
        global i
        i = i + 1

        global PGroup
        if i == 1:
            PGroup == 'Person_1'            
        elif i == 2:
            PGroup == 'Person_2'
        elif i == 3:
            PGroup == 'Person_3'


        urls = response.xpath("//a[@class='setPage'][contains(@href,'?page=')]/text()").getall()
        for url in urls:
            if url:              
                url_Ny = response.url +'?&page=' + url.strip()
                yield scrapy.Request(url= url_Ny, callback=self.parse_all, encoding='utf-8')


    def parse_all(self, response):
        for data in response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-6 col-md-4 product-wrap js-send-ga-product-click js-send-ga-products-impressions']"):
            item = {
                'Col_1' : data.xpath(".//@data-name").extract_first(),
                'Col_2': data.xpath(".//@data-brand").extract_first(),
                'Col_3' : PGroup,
                'Col_4': data.xpath(".//@data-price").extract_first(),
                'Col_5': d1,
            }
            yield item
```

Comment: Assignment is `=`, not with `==`.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks for correction. But still I am getting 'Person_3' in first url. However I am expecting 'Person_1' in first url. There seems to be code placement mistake.

Comment: Scrapy does not ensure that responses are handled in the source order. Consider, instead of using `start_urls`, implementing `start_requests` and yielding requests that include in their `cb_kwargs` or `meta` the desired `PGroup`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import scrapy
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

class NewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'LEARNING1'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.example/abc/',meta={"pg":"Person_1"}, callback=self.parse)
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.example/def/',meta={"pg":"Person_2"}, callback=self.parse)
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.example/ghi/',meta={"pg":"Person_3"}, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a[@class='setPage'][contains(@href,'?page=')]/text()").getall()        
        for url in urls:
            if url:              
                url_Ny = response.url +'?&page=' + url.strip()
                yield scrapy.Request(url= url_Ny, callback=self.parse_all,meta={"pg":response.meta["pg"]})

    def parse_all(self, response):
        for data in response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-6 col-md-4 product-wrap js-send-ga-product-click js-send-ga-products-impressions']"):
            item = {

                    'Col_1' : data.xpath(".//@data-name").extract_first(),
                    'Col_2': data.xpath(".//@data-brand").extract_first(),
                    'Col_3' : response.meta["pg"],
                    'Col_4': data.xpath(".//@data-price").extract_first(),
                    'Col_5': d1,
            }
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following part of your code:

```
global PGroup
    if i == 1:
        PGroup **==** 'Person_1'            
    elif i == 2:
        PGroup **==** 'Person_2'
    elif i == 3:
        PGroup **==** 'Person_3'
```

You are using **==**, which is used to check for equality. But in this case, you want to use the assignment operator **=** to set the variable PGroup equal to what you want. So, you should replace the above part of your code by:

```
global PGroup
        if i == 1:
            PGroup = 'Person_1'            
        elif i == 2:
            PGroup = 'Person_2'
        elif i == 3:
            PGroup = 'Person_3'
```